# AutoLayout issue Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, autolayout, uinavigationbar, iqkeyboardmanager

[image]

I have already `Autolayout` this screenshot using.I want when i click `textView`,textView will always just above Keyboard and also i am using custom `NavigationBar`.I already used `IQKeyBoardManagerSwift`It is working but my `NavigationBar` also moves up I want my `NavigationBar`to be stick at top if i click textView.Any Solutions to this. thanks in advance

Comment: for message scrolling have you used scrollview ? or your custom Navigation bar is in scrollview or in view ?

Comment: i also tried my all view except custom navigation in scrollview but still auto layout is not proper @CodeChanger could u help me with this

Comment: i m showing messages on tableview from json as well as when i enter text to textview it adds to tableview from api my custom Navigation bar is in View

Comment: @anujtiwari I think u should disable iqmanger in this controller and use constraint something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 5.0** :-  Drag your `UITextView` in a `contentView(UIView)`, Create `IBOutlet` of bottom constraint of contentView i.e `bottomConstraint`. After use the below code as mentioned and custom `NavigationBar` will also stick at top only textView will be just above keyboard.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Profile.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Profile.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
let keyboardSizeNow:CGSize = (userInfo.object(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSizeNow.height - 49
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 })
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide method in similar way

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            buttonBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let _ = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            bottomConstraint.constant = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
```

also, don't forget to observe in viewDidLoad.